# Unknown column username in 'where clause'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

I got this error when I try to select on table that one of its column is foreign key:

```
select count(*) from cards where username = 'name';
```

I am doing it through java jdbc so I think something with my mapping is wrong because the same query on through MySql commandline works just fine:

```
<many-to-one name="users" class="table" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="username" length="45" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

The

```
2013-03-02 12:19:03,660  INFO [http-bio-8080-exec-5] (NullableType.java:203) - could not read column value from result set: username; Column 'username' not found.
2013-03-02 12:19:03,663  WARN [http-bio-8080-exec-5] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:100) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2013-03-02 12:19:03,664 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-5] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:101) - Column 'username' not found.
```

---

I fount this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696

sections 16.1.2 and 16.1.3 probably the answer for my issue but I cant figure it out...

Comment: (1) Check that you're selecting from the right table. (2) Check that you're connecting to the right database.

Comment: yes I am for both 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

The error message states:

> could not read column value from result set: username; Column 'username' not found.

The result set for `select count(*) from ...` does not have a column named `username`. It only consists of one column, the count.

Comment: @user1692261: I am not sure I follow. You supply `'name'` to the query, and get back the count *for that name*.

Comment: This is a many to one table. for every usarname attributs there might be several rows in this table. For example, I want to count how many rows I have in the table for the username NPE.

Answer (score 0):

try to execute

```
 select count(*) from cards where `cards`.username='name';
```

Answer (score 0):

for get fields Should not use of "Select *".
should use of "select count(username) from cards where username = 'name';" expression.